# Getting issue to add time in existing date through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add the time 1 hours in existing date through jquery. I have tried javascript date object but didn't get the required result. I am using the following code.

```
 var sdate=new Date('2015-08-26T19:00');
 alert(sdate.getHours()+1);
```

I want to add 1 hours in 2015-08-26T19:00  date. Please let me know how I can get it

Comment: I don't believe jQuery provides date manipulation functionality. You might want to look into other libraries, like [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/), instead.

Comment: I tried it but it is conflicting with other jquery functions.

Comment: MomentJS is a terrific library, but it might be overkill depending on your use case.  What exactly is the issue that you're seeing?  What do you expect to be the output of the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need to do :

```
var sdate = new Date('2015-08-26T19:00');
var ndate = new Date(sdate.setHours(sdate.getHours() + 1));
alert(ndate);
```

Here's jsFiddle : **http://jsfiddle.net/zo3hh2ye/13/**

Comment: Yes but can I get the date in 2015-08-26T19:00 format

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle to reflect the date as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simple. Every hour is **60** Minutes. Each minute is **60** seconds. Each second is **1000** milliseconds. So every hour is **3600000** milliseconds. Now for date:

```
var sdate = new Date()
sdate.setMilliseconds(sdate.getMilliseconds()+3600000)
```

Comment: Yes. but I also want it in date like existing.

Comment: That will edit `sdate` object which is of type `Date`. Open your browser console and type that in.

Comment: It is showing the time in milisecond. I want the output in date like 2015-08-26T20:00

Comment: After typing the above in your browser console type `sdate`. It'll be the full `Date` object.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6734600/4888147

```
sdate.setHours(sdate.getHours() + hoursToAdd);
```

Comment: It is not working. showing in milisecond. how I can change milisecond in date format like existing date format that I am using

Comment: It is weird that you are getting it in milliseconds (I tested it and it's returning it correctly) but here is a solution: var ndate = new Date(sdate); -- Then just alert 'ndate'

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, I was using the current date, not your example date so I did get the milliseconds, but doing what I did in my previous comment changed it back.